# Cannot find module './package.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with 'json' extension

Tags: typescript, webstorm, vite

I'm using Vite.

In my `vite.config.ts` file, I have:

```js
import { resolve } from "node:path"

import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts"
import tsConfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths"

import pkg from "./package.json"

// Rest of config file
```

The error happens on `import pkg from "./package.json"`

The full error is: `TS2732: Cannot find module './package.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.`

`package.json` is most definitely a file, and the path to it is most definitely correct.

Both `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.vite.json` have these settings:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

This is not a matter of restarting the TypeScript service or IDE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not a universal answer, but I solved this by using the `vite-plugin-externalize-deps` library instead of trying to import `package.json` directly. Another solution might be to read `package.json` as a file instead of importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue, with `vite` project as well. Did 2 things to resolve it:

1. Add `"esModuleInterop": true` to all/both tsconfig files (as you did).
2. Add `.ts` files with the problem to tsconfig 'include', as `vite` projects usually include files from `./src` by default.

And always reload `vscode` after changing tsconfig: `Ctrl+Shift+P` -> `Reload Window`.